# Cannot log-in (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: login

I suddenly encountered the said issue just this afternoon. I've been able to login on my machine even if I weren't connected to our network. But all of a sudden, Ubuntu does not want to accept my login credentials. This machine is dual boot, and my login credentials are the same for both Ubuntu and Windows. I tried logging in to Windows and it worked. But with Ubuntu, it fails.

I tried logging in with a different account, and tried adding myself to the list of users. I canceled it cause I saw that my user directory still exists. It just seems like I've been removed from the list of users.

This may not be relevant but I checked the following files:

visudo

- my username is still there

/etc/passwd

- I'm not in this list. I didn't check before if it were.

I even tried going to the terminal side of logging in, and even there I didn't manage to get through. It's like all of a sudden, my user credentials disappeared from Ubuntu's memory.

I've tried the following:

Copy the .ICEauthority (in others this might be .Xauthority?) file from one user to my home folder, changed its permissions, but still nothing happens.

Any insight on how to solve this one?

Regards

UPDATE

@steeldriver:

I did what you asked and here's what happened (replaced 'username' with my username):

```
$ getent passwd username
$ 

$ ls -ld /home/username
drwx------ 35 1870676233 1870676233 4096 Jul 4 17:54 /home/username
```

Comment: Can you add the outputs of the commands `getent passwd username` and `ls -ld /home/username` (replacing `username` with your actual username) to your post please? You should be able to run those from any account (even an unprivileged one).

Comment: It seems your user is gone but your files are present. Add your user again but specify the uid and gid (the `adduser` command has options).

Comment: I shall try the two suggestions given to me here (in case one fails). I'll come back to you all after I've tried them. This message is just to show I've seen the comments/suggestions. Thanks for taking the time to respond to me!

Answer (score 0):

Safest way that I think of is to reboot into recovery and "recreate" your user  with the same user id and group id as the files in /home/

Here's how:
1. reboot in recovery mode
`cd /home`
`ls -lisa`
If the user  group doesn't have a name then you're gone from the system, note the numbers, first is user second is group.

```
useradd --home /home/<user> -M --uid <user number> --gid <group number> --shel /bin/dash  <user_name>
and then , 
passwd <user_name>
```

In this way you create a new user with the given password, and force it to use the old user id and group id, -M does not change the given home directory

If the command complains that the user is in the system, then  its group/uid might have changed somehow, then you can do a couple of things:

```
passwd <user_name> #to force a password
chown -R <user_name>:<user_name> /home/<user_name>
```

to forcefully reset all the ownership to your current user.

Or you could use usermod to change the current's user and group id to whatever you have in home.

Best of luck.

Comment: I haven't been able to try any of the two approaches. According to someone who checked the machine, the reason why I couldn't log in to my Ubuntu account was because I got disconnected from our domain. But the weird thing is, I was able to log into my machine before--even if I weren't connected to our network. It seems like my log-in credentials are stored somewhere else, but not in my local machine, it seems. That one I need to get addressed. Thanks for the replies, though!